# Exception on buildDockerImage. Cannot access input property 'inputDir' of task ':project-name:buildDockerImage'

Tags: java, docker, gradle

i was recently updating gradle to 8.5 in my spring-boot project and got this exception when executing my buildDockerImage task in gradle tasks file.

Exception:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project-name:buildDockerImage'.
> Cannot access input property 'inputDir' of task ':project-name:buildDockerImage'. Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/incremental_build.html#disable-state-tracking in the Gradle documentation.
   > Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of
> the file
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.doHash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:35)
        ... 115 more
```

Task Code:

```
task buildDockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    inputDir = project.projectDir
    (...)
}
```

I have upgraded com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin to 6.7.0 but it didn't fix this issue.

Previously on gradle 6.8.3 task was working fine.
We also upgraded java from 11 to 17.
I am running this task from IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4

EDIT: Task seems to be working on gitlab pipeline. Might be Windows issue.